# Agreed columns in pandas

Tags: python

I was making a frequency table with the following data:

Pedidos.csv

```
65 98 55 62 79 59 51 90 72 56 70 62 66 80 94 79 63 73 71 85
```

I carry out the following procedure:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
datos= pd.read_csv('tipo.csv')
t=datos.iloc[1:,1].values.tolist()
lo=np.sort(t,axis=None)
f=pd.Series(lo).value_counts()
f1=pd.DataFrame({'frecuencias':f})
print(f1)
```

but it does not return a column with the name of the variable to which that frequency corresponds when running to the left side you show me but it is not a columnist

Comment: what does `pero no me devuelve una columna con el nombre de la variable a la que corresponde esa frecuencia al correr al lado izquierdo me las muestras pero no es una columana` mean? can you please write it in english...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are trying to ask, but if you want something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy  as np


li=[65, 98, 55, 62, 79, 59, 51, 90, 72, 56, 70, 62, 66, 80, 94, 79, 63, 73, 71, 85]
datos= pd.DataFrame(li)
t=datos.values.tolist()

lo=np.sort(t,axis=None)

f=pd.Series(lo).value_counts()

f1=pd.DataFrame({'frecuencias':f})

print(f1)
```

Try this

output:

```
frecuencias
62            2
79            2
63            1
66            1
70            1
71            1
72            1
73            1
80            1
51            1
85            1
55            1
56            1
94            1
90            1
59            1
98            1
65            1
```

Comment: that data frame has 2 columns, in column 0 are the variables and in 1 the frequencies?
That's what I want to be able to modify to add title and one more row where it says total and put the sum that is 20

Comment: that you can simply do by using append()  df=df.append({'variables':'Total', 'frequencies':20})